# Dump data to yml in Play! Framework

Tags: playframework

Is there a way to dump data (generated with the CRUD) into a yml data file?

This feature is available in Rails, Django, etc...

I find that the best way to create data and respect relationships is throught the CRUD admin

There's nothing about it in the [Play! Yaml Documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/yaml)

I will add that it would be nice if possible to dump while using the mem (or fs) databases, though this means it cannot be done with a "play" command but could be done through a special Route maybe?

In short:

- is there any existing 'dump' code in Play! ?
- is it possible to dump via a `$play dumpdata` command?
- is it possible to dump via special Route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want the [logisimayml](http://www.playframework.org/modules/logisimayml) module.

> To export your database, simply type this command line :
>
> play yml:generate

You should have a look through the [Play Modules page](http://www.playframework.org/modules). Lots of great stuff there.

Comment: Perfect! I still find play documentation difficult to browse.. or maybe just not well indexed by google! I will have to play around a little to see how it behaves with the mem db, but I guess I can always start play with "start" then issue the generate command.

Comment: It seems the module is just for 1.x play version, I need to use this with play 2. Is there anything similar?